# Building the argument for FREETEXT or CONTAINS from a user search string

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, search, full-text-indexing

Is there a time-tested library/algorithm for generating the arguments for CONTAINS or FREETEXT from the text a user enters into a search box?

I'm hoping to replace poorly implemented (who me?) code that generates SQL from a users "free text" entry in a search box.

- Sanitizing text to escape sql keywords
- Breaking down and organizing the text so that it makes sense to CONTAINS?
- Same for FREETEXT (though for some reason I don't think I'm using this)